# Grid child is already another visual or the root of a compositionTarget

Tags: c#, wpf, children

I want in set all images from list to grid. But I have problem with adding second image in grid with `Children.Add`.
Here is my example:

```
 List<Image> images = new List<Image>(8);
 images.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new Image(), 8));//8 empty images
```

Then setting images:

```
foreach (var image in images)
{
  BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
  b.BeginInit();
  b.UriSource = new Uri("path");
  b.EndInit();
  image.Source = b;
  image.Width = 50;
  image.Height = 50;
}
```

Then in one function call like this:

```
private void put_images()
{
  int i = 0;
  foreach (var image in images)
  {
    Grid.SetRow(image, i);
    Grid.SetColumn(image, i);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);//here is error
    i++;
  }
}
```

I got runtime error: `Additional information: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.`

I don't understand why, because I got 8 different images, and I don't know how to fix that problem.

Comment: Is there XAML to go along with this? Are you 100% sure LayoutRoot is the the Grid you expect it to be?

Comment: It seems like the image in question was added as a child before you added it to LayoutRoot. Have you checked if `image.Parent` is null?

Comment: I find problem. I answer that.

Comment: I know you already found a solution, nonetheless I added an answer with a detailed problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the code where you create the images.

```
images.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new Image(), 8));
```

This is one image object, with 8 references in the collection.

The documentation of [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348899%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says:

> element
>       Type: TResult
>       The **value** to be repeated.

The value of `new Image()` is the **reference** to that Image.
Which means you have 8 references to the same object in the collection.

You can easily verify that by comparing the first with the second entry in the list.

```
images[0] == images[1] //=true
```

---

A **solution** would be to use a `for` loop to instantiate the images.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) images.Add(new Image());
```

Comment: This is very interestic and logic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems the problem is the creating images. 
Now I don't create 8 empty images, but I create Image, and then add in list. Now it's work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  Image a = new Image();
  BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
  b.BeginInit();
  b.UriSource = new Uri("path");
  b.EndInit();
  a.Source = b;
  a.Width = 50;
  a.Height = 50;
  images.Add(a);
}
```